# Convert the index of a Timeseries from datetime64[ns] to datetime64[s] without loosing information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I'm working on a Timeseries indexed by timestamps with precision of ns but in reality it should be one every second. I need to convert this timestamps in seconds because I want to extract some periodical patterns, and sometimes I have missing data point that I will interpolate after resampling the converted datatimes every second.

```
data = np.array([["2019-07-12 10:39:17.817000+00:00", 45],["2019-07-12 10:39:19.007000+00:00", 45],["2019-07-12 10:39:19.996000+00:00", 40],["2019-07-12 10:39:20.497000+00:00", 1],["2019-07-12 10:39:21.489000+00:00", 10],["2019-07-12 10:39:22.498000+00:00", 3],["2019-07-12 10:39:23.491000+00:00", 5],["2019-07-12 10:39:24.501000+00:00", 15],["2019-07-12 10:39:25.495000+00:00", 8],["2019-07-12 10:39:26.489000+00:00", 3],["2019-07-12 10:39:27.497000+00:00", 90],["2019-07-12 10:39:28.490000+00:00", 4],["2019-07-12 10:39:29.498000+00:00", 37],["2019-07-12 10:39:30.490000+00:00", 55]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data[:, 1], index=data[:, 0], columns=["value"])
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print(df.to_string())
                                 value
2019-07-12 10:39:17.817000+00:00    45
2019-07-12 10:39:19.007000+00:00    45
2019-07-12 10:39:19.996000+00:00    40
2019-07-12 10:39:20.497000+00:00     1
2019-07-12 10:39:21.489000+00:00    10
2019-07-12 10:39:22.498000+00:00     3
2019-07-12 10:39:23.491000+00:00     5
2019-07-12 10:39:24.501000+00:00    15
2019-07-12 10:39:25.495000+00:00     8
2019-07-12 10:39:26.489000+00:00     3
2019-07-12 10:39:27.497000+00:00    90
2019-07-12 10:39:28.490000+00:00     4
2019-07-12 10:39:29.498000+00:00    37
2019-07-12 10:39:30.490000+00:00    55
```

What I want is to convert the datetimes in seconds but by doing this I have duplicated values:

```
df.index = df.index.round(freq="S")
print(df.to_string())
                          value
2019-07-12 10:39:18+00:00    45
2019-07-12 10:39:19+00:00    45
2019-07-12 10:39:20+00:00    40
2019-07-12 10:39:20+00:00     1
2019-07-12 10:39:21+00:00    10
2019-07-12 10:39:22+00:00     3
2019-07-12 10:39:23+00:00     5
2019-07-12 10:39:25+00:00    15
2019-07-12 10:39:25+00:00     8
2019-07-12 10:39:26+00:00     3
2019-07-12 10:39:27+00:00    90
2019-07-12 10:39:28+00:00     4
2019-07-12 10:39:29+00:00    37
2019-07-12 10:39:30+00:00    55
```

Even if I choose floor instead of round it won't work because of these values:

```
2019-07-12 10:39:19.007000+00:00
2019-07-12 10:39:19.996000+00:00
```

Is there a way to convert the datetime in seconds so that it doesn't create duplicated values ?

Expected output:

```
                          value
2019-07-12 10:39:17+00:00    45
2019-07-12 10:39:18+00:00    45
2019-07-12 10:39:19+00:00    40
2019-07-12 10:39:20+00:00     1
2019-07-12 10:39:21+00:00    10
2019-07-12 10:39:22+00:00     3
2019-07-12 10:39:23+00:00     5
2019-07-12 10:39:24+00:00    15
2019-07-12 10:39:25+00:00     8
2019-07-12 10:39:26+00:00     3
2019-07-12 10:39:27+00:00    90
2019-07-12 10:39:28+00:00     4
2019-07-12 10:39:29+00:00    37
2019-07-12 10:39:30+00:00    55
```

Comment: I guess a better approach than rounding would be to upsample your data to a fixed frequency by interpolating, then downsampling it (again by interpolation if your upsampled frequency is not a multiple of the final frequency). There is no way of downsampling without losing information though (unless your signal is oversampled in the first place).

Comment: Yes I know I'm asking a lot by saying I don't want to lose information :), sadly it is not an oversampled signal and like all real data, it has not been well gathered. Thanks, I'll try what you explained, I'm kinda new to using time series so I might take a while but I'll let you know if it is better.

Comment: Why did second 18 get a value, although it had none in the first dataframe? Because I think you simply want: `df.resample('S').sum()`

Comment: have you considered normalizing the time series?

Comment: @Erfan because the machine made a mistake by sending the data too late but in theory I should have one measurement per second, sometimes it appears like I have two for one second but it is because it was meant for one second before/after.

Comment: @AnnaNevison what do you mean by normalizing? Sorry kinda new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first round to the nearest 100ms and then use ceil to round up to the nearest second, you will get your desired output.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('something.csv')

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
print(df)

df['time'] = df['time'].dt.round('100ms')
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.ceil('1s')
print(df)
```

output:

```
0  2019-07-12 10:39:18+00:00     45
1  2019-07-12 10:39:19+00:00     45
2  2019-07-12 10:39:20+00:00     40
3  2019-07-12 10:39:21+00:00      1
4  2019-07-12 10:39:22+00:00     10
5  2019-07-12 10:39:23+00:00      3
6  2019-07-12 10:39:24+00:00      5
7  2019-07-12 10:39:25+00:00     15
8  2019-07-12 10:39:26+00:00      8
9  2019-07-12 10:39:27+00:00      3
10 2019-07-12 10:39:28+00:00     90
11 2019-07-12 10:39:29+00:00      4
12 2019-07-12 10:39:30+00:00     37
13 2019-07-12 10:39:31+00:00     55
```

Comment: Thank you it seems to work quite well on my real dataset but some duplicates are still created because of some cases like this one:
`2019-07-19 06:29:01.057000+02:00`,
`2019-07-19 06:29:02.049000+02:00` So it rounds to second 2 for the both rows. I tried to remove one second to the rows that have duplicates and I succedeed in reducing a lot the number of duplicates. Although I still have some of them but I guess I can't have a perfect result.

Comment: @SmileyProd can you post a new question with your updated data set after using this? I may have some ideas..